# Name Server for a domain name is its own sub domain - How to do that?

Tags: nameserver

I want to assign nameservers for a domainname to its subdomain, similar to what google did. that is for `google.com` the name servers are `ns1.google.com` - `ns4.google.com`. I can setup a DNS Server. The part which I can't figure out as of now is how can I assign IP Address to `ns1.example.com` - `nsX.example.com` while making them nameserver for `example.com`.

If I am not wrong then I have to make a request to my domainname registrar for setting it up for me. If it is so, what should I ask my registrar for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assign them an IP like you would assign an IP for any other server. The only difference is that you want to register a [glue record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records) in order to avoid the circular dependency that develops when your DNS servers are authoritative for a domain that they are a subdomain of.

Comment: yes. glue record. i read about it somewhere long back and can't remember what its called. anyway thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

They host their own DNS servers.

Example:

If you own example.com then you would host your own servers at your location running DNS.

So you build up ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com at your offices (or your cloud, etc.) and make them authoritative for example.com.

Then you login to your registrar's control panel (say Network Solutions) and set the name servers for example.com to point to ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com.

Comment: The difference is that they'll need the IP addresses as well and they'll need to add glue records. When nameservers serve their own zone, you can't very well ask them for their own IP addresses. (Because you need to already know the IP address in order to query.)

Comment: how shall I make `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com` authoritative?

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. He's asking how anyone will be able to resolve `ns1.example.com` to get the address for `example.com`, since to be able to resolve `ns1.example.com` you first need to be able to contact the name servers for that site, thus the need for glue records which break this circular dependency.

Comment: MDMarra, yep sorry, I did overlook what his real question was.